# Yosemite: Backslash key doesn't work

Tags: macos

My backslash key stopped working after upgrading to yosemite last week. Also, whenever i restart my mac system starts typing backslash on any textbox. It doesn't stop until i hit backspace.

Comment: Cleaned your keyboard lately???

Comment: Try repeatedly button mashing the backslash key

Comment: How does an external keyboard behave?

Comment: @emilycurious took out the key cleaned it, doesnt' seem a hardware issue.

Comment: @CousinCocaine yes, external keyboard works. But, thats a microsoft wireless keyboard and uses its own driver so can't say much here.

Comment: When an external keyboard works ok, that makes damage to the internal one very likely.

Comment: @TomGewecke yes damage was internal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

backslash key was permanently pressed. Nothing related to yosemite. Used Karabiner to disable that key.